Shifting values up rows in a dataframe in R by group
I have a dataframe in R where I need to shift the values up in a particular column using a numeric value. The numeric value which is used as input to shift the values up are associated with a grouping variable and are often different from group to group. Here is an example of a mock dataframe
mock data frame
df<-data.frame(ID=c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c"),
               var_description = c("description 1", "description 2","description 3","description 4","description 5",
                                   "description 1", "description 2","description 3","description 4","description 5",
                                   "description 1", "description 2","description 3","description 4","description 5"),
               var_value = c(NA,NA,NA,"desc 1 val","desc 2 val",
                             NA,"desc 1 val","desc 2 val","desc 3 val","desc 4 val",
                             NA,NA,NA,NA,"desc 1 val"),
               shift_val = c(3,3,3,3,3,
                             1,1,1,1,1,
                             4,4,4,4,4))


Here is the current working solution:-

#getting unique vals
unique_id = unique(df$ID)

#initialising dataframe to collect results
df_results<-data.frame()


#function to shift values up
shift <- function(x,n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))],rep(NA,n))
}


#for loop

for (i in unique_id) {
  
  #filtering by each ID
  one_id<-df%>%filter(ID==i)
  
  #getting value to shift values by
  Move_by_val = unique(one_id$shift_val)
  #shifting
  one_id$new_var_value<-shift(one_id$var_value, Move_by_val)
  
  #binding one_id onto df_results
  
  df_results<-rbind(df_results,one_id)
  
}


head(df_results,10)

# ID var_description  var_value shift_val new_var_value
# 1   a   description 1       <NA>         3    desc 1 val
# 2   a   description 2       <NA>         3    desc 2 val
# 3   a   description 3       <NA>         3          <NA>
# 4   a   description 4 desc 1 val         3          <NA>
# 5   a   description 5 desc 2 val         3          <NA>
# 6   b   description 1       <NA>         1    desc 1 val
# 7   b   description 2 desc 1 val         1    desc 2 val
# 8   b   description 3 desc 2 val         1    desc 3 val
# 9   b   description 4 desc 3 val         1    desc 4 val
# 10  b   description 5 desc 4 val         1          <NA>



Using the shift_val which is associated with each unique df$ID, I am able to shift the var_value up, where the value matches the var_description, as represented in the column new_var_value.
The current solution I am using works but when applied to a much larger dataframe (such as one that is ~ >100k rows), it becomes slow and inefficient.
Can someone recommend an alternative solution which gives me the same output as the one I have but has potential to be much more efficient? perhaps a {data.table} or {purrr} solution might be best, but I am not well versed in either.
R version: 3.6.1

Here is a purrr option that should run on older versions:
library(purrr)

shift <- function(dat){
  amt <- dat$shift_val[1]
  within(dat, new_var_val <-  c(dat$var_value[-seq_len(amt)], rep(NA, amt)))
}

df %>% 
  split(. , .$ID) %>% 
  map_dfr(shift)

Output
   ID var_description  var_value shift_val new_var_val
1   a   description 1       <NA>         3  desc 1 val
2   a   description 2       <NA>         3  desc 2 val
3   a   description 3       <NA>         3        <NA>
4   a   description 4 desc 1 val         3        <NA>
5   a   description 5 desc 2 val         3        <NA>
6   b   description 1       <NA>         1  desc 1 val
7   b   description 2 desc 1 val         1  desc 2 val
8   b   description 3 desc 2 val         1  desc 3 val
9   b   description 4 desc 3 val         1  desc 4 val
10  b   description 5 desc 4 val         1        <NA>
11  c   description 1       <NA>         4  desc 1 val
12  c   description 2       <NA>         4        <NA>
13  c   description 3       <NA>         4        <NA>
14  c   description 4       <NA>         4        <NA>
15  c   description 5 desc 1 val         4        <NA>


Using your shift()
shift = function(x, k) c(x[-seq(k)], rep(NA, k)) # replaced n by k 

try
EDIT
This probably runs on older versions of R sufficiently fast,
Reduce(
   tapply(df, df$ID, \(i) transform(i, new_var_value = shift(var_description, shift_val[[1L]]))
    ), f = rbind)

is a classic split-apply-combine approach, and pure base R (no dependencies). Gives
   ID var_description  var_value shift_val new_var_value
1   a   description 1       <NA>         3    desc 1 val
2   a   description 2       <NA>         3    desc 2 val
3   a   description 3       <NA>         3          <NA>
4   a   description 4 desc 1 val         3          <NA>
5   a   description 5 desc 2 val         3          <NA>
6   b   description 1       <NA>         1    desc 1 val
7   b   description 2 desc 1 val         1    desc 2 val
8   b   description 3 desc 2 val         1    desc 3 val
9   b   description 4 desc 3 val         1    desc 4 val
10  b   description 5 desc 4 val         1          <NA>
11  c   description 1       <NA>         4    desc 1 val
12  c   description 2       <NA>         4          <NA>
13  c   description 3       <NA>         4          <NA>
14  c   description 4       <NA>         4          <NA>
15  c   description 5 desc 1 val         4          <NA>

ORIGINAL deleted

Data
df = data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c"),
               var_description = c("description 1", "description 2","description 3","description 4","description 5",
                                   "description 1", "description 2","description 3","description 4","description 5",
                                   "description 1", "description 2","description 3","description 4","description 5"),
               var_value = c(NA,NA,NA,"desc 1 val","desc 2 val",
                             NA,"desc 1 val","desc 2 val","desc 3 val","desc 4 val",
                             NA,NA,NA,NA,"desc 1 val"),
               shift_val = c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4))


simply use lead from dplyr:
Edit: since you are using older version use:
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(var_value1 = lead(var_value, shift_val[1])) %>%
   ungroup()


df %>%
   mutate(var_value1 = lead(var_value,shift_val[1]), .by = ID)

   ID var_description  var_value shift_val var_value1
1   a   description 1       <NA>         3 desc 1 val
2   a   description 2       <NA>         3 desc 2 val
3   a   description 3       <NA>         3       <NA>
4   a   description 4 desc 1 val         3       <NA>
5   a   description 5 desc 2 val         3       <NA>
6   b   description 1       <NA>         1 desc 1 val
7   b   description 2 desc 1 val         1 desc 2 val
8   b   description 3 desc 2 val         1 desc 3 val
9   b   description 4 desc 3 val         1 desc 4 val
10  b   description 5 desc 4 val         1       <NA>
11  c   description 1       <NA>         4 desc 1 val
12  c   description 2       <NA>         4       <NA>
13  c   description 3       <NA>         4       <NA>
14  c   description 4       <NA>         4       <NA>
15  c   description 5 desc 1 val         4       <NA>


FYI, user seems to be running an older version of R so I doubt .by is available. OP might want to pipe to group_by(ID).

Using data.table. First we get rid of the unnecessary repeats in the shift_val and move the information to another table.
library(data.table)
setDT(df)


df_shift <- df[, unique(.SD), .SDcols = c("ID", "shift_val")]
setkey(df_shift, "ID") # For faster lookup
get_n <- \(id) df_shift[unlist(id), shift_val]
df[, shift_val := NULL] 

df[, var_value := shift(var_value, n = get_n(.BY)),  by = ID]


#         ID var_description  var_value
#     <char>          <char>     <char>
#  1:      a   description 1 desc 1 val
#  2:      a   description 2 desc 2 val
#  3:      a   description 3       <NA>
#  4:      a   description 4       <NA>
#  5:      a   description 5       <NA>
#  6:      b   description 1 desc 1 val
#  7:      b   description 2 desc 2 val
#  8:      b   description 3 desc 3 val
#  9:      b   description 4 desc 4 val
# 10:      b   description 5       <NA>
# 11:      c   description 1 desc 1 val
# 12:      c   description 2       <NA>
# 13:      c   description 3       <NA>
# 14:      c   description 4       <NA>
# 15:      c   description 5       <NA>


Thank you for this, I am working with an older version of R (3.6.1) and when running the solution, the get_n <- \(id) df_shift[unlist(id), shift_val] causes an error. Is there a way to adapt this to run on my current version, please? Thanks

@metaltoaster, I think it might be helpful if you add some information about your session to your question, such as R version and package versions for dplyr, purrr, and data.table so users aren't guessing what might run for you.

Thank you @LMc, I will update now.

@metaltoaster. Use function(id)  instead of \(id) on older R
